# Error " MemoryError" while using MultiProcessPool to get count of files inside a folder

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, out-of-memory, pool

i have a code which counts the number of file inside a folder using MultiProcessPool , but now it is throwing me Memory Error , am new to the concept of multiprocessing and multithreading . I wrote code for MultiProcessing and MultiThreading for doing the same function . Both are throwing me error :

**Code for Multiprocessing:**

```
def findfiles(taggedrootdir,files):
    taggedrootdir = pathlib.Path(taggedrootdir)

    if ((len(files)) > 0):
        oldest_file = (
            min([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))
        newest_file = (
            max([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))
        c_time_of_oldest = os.path.getctime(oldest_file)
        local_time_of_oldest = time.ctime(c_time_of_oldest)

        c_time_of_newest = os.path.getctime(newest_file)
        local_time_of_newest = time.ctime(c_time_of_newest)

    elif ((len(files)) == 0):
        local_time_of_oldest = "No File in Path"
        local_time_of_newest = "No File in Path"

    # print("{} --> {} --> {} --> {}".format(len(files), root,local_time_of_oldest,local_time_of_newest))
    fileStatsObj = os.stat(taggedrootdir)
    modificationTime = time.ctime(fileStatsObj[stat.ST_MTIME])

    folderstat = {}
    folderstat['FolderPath'] = taggedrootdir
    folderstat['count'] = len(files)
    folderstat['OldestTimeStamp'] = local_time_of_oldest
    folderstat['NewestTimeStamp'] = local_time_of_newest
    folderstat['FolderModificationTime'] = modificationTime

    return folderstat

if __name__ == '__main__':

    roots = r'Path'

    start_time = time.time()

    args = ((root, files) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(roots))

    for result in Pool().starmap(findfiles, args):
       
        with open('MultiProcessPool.csv', 'a') as f:
            for key in result.keys():
                f.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, result[key]))

    print('--- %s seconds ---' % (time.time() - start_time))
```

**Error:**

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 713, in __str__
    return self._str
AttributeError: _str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 715, in __str__
    self._str = self._format_parsed_parts(self._drv, self._root,
  File "C:\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 695, in _format_parsed_parts
    return drv + root + cls._flavour.join(parts[1:])
```

**Code for MultiThreading :**

```
root = roots = r'Path'
count_of_file = 0

import pathlib
noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0
def Count_files_in_subd():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(roots):
        taggedrootdir = pathlib.Path(root)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=findfiles, args=(taggedrootdir,files,))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()


def findfiles(taggedrootdir,files):
    if ((len(files)) > 0):
        oldest_file = (
            min([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))
        newest_file = (
            max([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))
        c_time_of_oldest = os.path.getctime(oldest_file)
        local_time_of_oldest = time.ctime(c_time_of_oldest)

        c_time_of_newest = os.path.getctime(newest_file)
        local_time_of_newest = time.ctime(c_time_of_newest)

    elif ((len(files)) == 0):
        local_time_of_oldest = "No File in Path"
        local_time_of_newest = "No File in Path"

    fileStatsObj = os.stat(taggedrootdir)
    modificationTime = time.ctime(fileStatsObj[stat.ST_MTIME])

    folderstat = {}
    folderstat['FolderPath'] = taggedrootdir
    folderstat['count'] = len(files)
    folderstat['OldestTimeStamp'] = local_time_of_oldest
    folderstat['NewestTimeStamp'] = local_time_of_newest
    folderstat['FolderModificationTime'] = modificationTime

    with open('MultiThreading.csv', 'a') as f:
        for key in folderstat.keys():
            f.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, folderstat[key]))
    # print(folderstat)


start_time = time.time()
Count_files_in_subd()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 758, in __hash__
    return self._hash
AttributeError: _hash

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 746, in _cparts
    return self._cached_cparts
AttributeError: _cached_cparts
```

Comment: Actually you do not need either `multiprocessing` or `multithreading` for counting number of files, just make simple app and go with `glob`

Comment: i have more than 10k files in a folder , if using glob it wil take time right , i want to speed up that process @ArtiomKozyrev

Comment: The problem is that to only count number of files in folder is not really heavy operation, so to distribute tasks over processes can even get more time than counting files. Heavy CPU operations are operations like e.g. `2**1000000000`

Comment: sorry i checked that too , but there was a lot in difference if timing , multiprocess was executed faster compared to glob and multithreading @ArtiomKozyrev